# Hibernate - @OneToMany - com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a problem with OneToMany relations.
I'm using spring-mvc and spring-security and hibernate 4.

I'm using annotations for all.

My problem is in the entity War when I see the atributte List players debugging, I see `players= PersistentBag` and when I click it `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.`

Also I get this Exceptions:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: clanwar.model.War.players, could not initialize proxy - no Session

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: clanwar.model.War.players, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WARS")
public class War implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLAN")
    private Clan clan;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "ENEMY_NAME")
    private String enemyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "war")
    private List<WarPlayer> players;

    @Transient
    private List<Enemy> enemies;

    public War() { }

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

--

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WAR_PLAYERS")
public class WarPlayer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WAR")
    private War war;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYER")
    private Player player;

    @Column(name = "WAR_NUMBER")
    private int warNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJETIVE_1")
    private Attack objetive1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJETIVE_2")
    private Attack objetive2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECOMMENDED_1")
    private Attack recommended1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECOMMENDED_2")
    private Attack recommended2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FINAL_1")
    private Attack final1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FINAL_2")
    private Attack final2;
    private String comment;

    public WarPlayer() {}

    // Getters and setters

}
```

My DAO

```
@Override
    public War findById(int id) throws DaoException {

        War war;

        try {
            war = (War) getSession()
                    .createQuery("from War where ID = :id")
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return war;
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hibernate documentation says:

> In the normal case the orders association would be lazy loaded by
>   Hibernate

So, you need to use eager fetching:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "war",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<WarPlayer> players;
```

Comment: I dont want to load the childrens first. I want to use lazy loading but still can this issue will be fixed?

Comment: @ManjunathM Did you use @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)annotation in your DAO method? If you did so, change it to "SUPPORTS", "REQUIRED" or "MANDATORY". This could work for you ;)

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I always see the performance issue with eager fetch type.

Answer (score 2):

FetchType.EAGER is not efficient. You must include the org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch annotation.

So:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "war", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<WarPlayer> players;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace My Dao

```
@Override
public War findById(int id) throws DaoException {

    Transaction transaction = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "from War where ID = :id";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

                query.setParameter("id", id).uniqueResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e.getMessage());
    }

    return war;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to say I have @Transactional annotation. With this I get the same error. My problem solved with the Tkachuk_Evgen aswer

Answer (score 0):

In my case it  is because I was doing

```
@Query("SELECT amg FROM AgentmasterGroup amg WHERE amg.merchantmaster.id=:merchantId")

List<Map<String,Object>> findAgentmasterGroupByMerchantId(@Param("merchantId") Integer merchantId);
```

since `jpa` did not return entity as `List<Map<String,Object>>` when we select by alias of entity, so we need to do:

```
@Query("SELECT amg FROM AgentmasterGroup amg WHERE amg.merchantmaster.id=:merchantId")

List<AgentmasterGroup> findAgentmasterGroupByMerchantId(@Param("merchantId") Integer merchantId);
```

after that we can convert list of entity to list of map.
or we can also do `select` query as:

```
@Query("SELECT amg.id as id, amg.name as name  FROM AgentmasterGroup amg WHERE amg.merchantmaster.id=:merchantId")

List<Map<String,Object>> findAgentmasterGroupByMerchantId(@Param("merchantId") Integer merchantId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue pops with latest ver of spring-data jpa versions.

If underlying DB is not having the data corresponding to id, we get above error. (both null check fails and not a valid entity object as well)

If so better to use the optional API like this. using it it will return either null or valid entity object.

```
@Resource
RegionRepo regionRepo;

regionRepo.findById(id).orElse(null);

RegionRepo is interface extends JpaRepository
```